# 2D Sprite Batching

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, sprite

I'm currently calling `glDrawElements` for each sprite in a 2D scene. I want to change this.

The scene is composed to an offscreen render buffer (an FBO), and there is currently only one sprite-sheet texture being used to compose the entire scene.

If I queue up all the `glDrawElements` into a single large buffer, I think that would work, but... in the future (when I have more than one sprite-sheet texture) would I have to commit the current buffer each time a call to `glBindTexture` is required?

The reason I ask (for this ordinarily obvious question) is that FBOs have a depth buffer, and that has me wondering if the order in which I draw the sprites could be insignificant (meaning I could draw all the sprites for one texture, and then draw all the sprites for the other texture, and ignore the order in which I draw them (using the Z axis to sort them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's no blending involved the order does in fact not matter. But there's a better approach: using a textue atlas.

That means to use one draw call to draw all sprites and to include texture coordinates to select which sprite to use. The (single) texture simply contains all sprites side by side.

Comment: Unless a texture atlas is allowed to exceed the maximum texture size restriction of the OpenGL implementation, it's useless in my case. My sprite sheet is built using a tool of mine, to be as optimal as possible for a given maximum texture size.